# Isolated Storage & Saving Multiple Objects

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I wish to know what the best way is to create Saving and Loading logic so that I can save and load x items. For example, in Isolated Storage I can easily save a composite/POCO object by doing this:

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
settings.Add("key", myObject);
```

And load like this:

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
return settings["key"] as MyObject;
```

But how would I load x amount of Objects from IsolatedStorage? Would it be best to create a `List<MyObject>` collection and save and whenever I want to save another object I basically load the existing and do `.Add(newObject)` and save again?

So something like this:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();
myObjects.Add(newObject);
settings.Add("myObjects", myObjects);
```

and when Loading:

```
var myObjects = settings["myObjects"] as List<MyObject>;
```

This would however require deleting and adding the collection back in as `settings.Add` requires a unique key. Would this be the best way?

I'd much rather use settings than a Iso File.

Comment: What I did is create an xml file and replace it every time you have to save something. It's working fine if you don't save the data very often and your data is small. Other then that you should use a "real" database

Answer (score 1):

Due to MSDN : IsolatedStorageSettings provide a convenient way to store user specific data as key-value pairs in a local IsolatedStorageFile. A typical use is to save settings, such as the number of images to display per page, page layout options, and so on.

so I don't think that using IsolatedStorageSettings would be your best option , if I were you , I would use IsolatedStorageFile.

To save and load the content of your list , the scenario would be

1- if an item is added or removed from your list , you searlize the list to xml and save it IsolatedStorageFile

```
 private static void Serialize(string fileName, object source)
    {
        var userStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, userStore))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(source.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(stream, source);
        }
    }
```

2- When you want to load your list at any place , you would deserialize the xml file stored in IsolatedStorageFile

```
public static void Deserialize<T>(ObservableCollection<T> list , string filename)
    {

        list = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        var userStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (userStore.FileExists(filename))
        {
            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, userStore))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
                var items = (ObservableCollection<T>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    list.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed. Thanks a lot for that. Can I use that code as is without any modifications? And in the first section of your code, would it be better to use FileMode.OpenOrCreate?

Comment: urw , I believe you can do so ! In fact I can't decide which is better (from performance prespective , may be FileMode.OpenorCreate) but what I know is that FileMode.Create would overwrite the file if it already exists otherwise create a new one and that is what I need in this code. Finally , If you used FileMode.OpenorCreate , it will cause an exception when you try to deserialize the xml file.

Comment: In the code, I don't see you saving anything. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Try to read more about the XmlSerializer class and serialze and deserialize methods
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552.aspx

Serialize method serializes the specified Object and writes the XML document to a file using the specified Stream and the stream is created using

var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename , FileMode.Open  , userstore);