# Saving ObservableCollection to isolated storage

Tags: c#, class, xaml, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am in the process of making a note taking app, in which the user can create, edit and delete notes. Once the app is closed all data should be stored in isolated storage. I have created a note class which sets some properties below:

```
    public string strNoteName { get; set; }
    public string strCreated { get; set; }
    public string strModified { get; set; }
    public bool boolIsProtected { get; set; }
    public string strNoteImage { get; set; }
    public string strNoteSubject { get; set; }
    public string strTextContent { get; set; }
```

These are put into an `ObservableCollection<note> GetnotesRecord()` which can be displayed in the Mainpage using a listbox. On touch there is an event handler for `SelectionChange` which passes the item to the editpage where items such as strTextContent and strNoteName can be edited.

After adding all this, I want the data to be saved to isolated storage so it can be loaded next time the app runs.

Is it possible to save an `ObservableCollection<note>`? If yes, how can it be retrieved from the isolated storage when I'm starting the app later?

Comment: You should update your title to make tit clear you want to figure out how to persist values in your WP8 app, rather than describing what your app is about.

Comment: Tip: Avoid Hungarian notation and use `PascalCase` for public members.

Comment: Did you try to save your collection? What happened when you tried? If you are unsure of how to save object, have you looked into serialization? What did you research in regards to saving a list?

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate, although it doesn't have any accepted answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197696/isolated-storage-saving-multiple-objects?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps :-

If you collection is big then convert your ObservalbleCollection to a xml string and store it using `IsolatedStorageSettings` class as a Key-Value pair.

If it is not :- 
then you can IsolatedStorageSettings directly like this

```
IsolatedStorageSettings Store { get { return IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings; } }

    public T GetValue<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)Store[key];
    }

    public void SetValue(string token, object value)
    {
        Store.Add(token, value);
        Store.Save();
    }
```

Usage :-

```
    ObservableCollection<Note> objCollection = new ObservableCollection<Note>()
    {
        new Note(){Checkbool = false,Checkme = "sd"},
        new Note(){Checkbool = false,Checkme = "sd1"},
        new Note(){Checkbool = false,Checkme = "sd2"}
    };

    // you can also make check whether values are present or 
    // by checking the key in storage.
    var isContainKey = Store.Contains("set")

    // save key value pair
    SetValue("set", objCollection); 

    // extract key value pair
    var value = GetValue<ObservableCollection<Note>>("set");
```