# Saving lists (String) to application/isolated storage (Win8.1)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, isolatedstorage

I have a list of multiple strings which I would like to save to IsolatedStorage. Doing something obvious like

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["locations"] = l;
```

Results in a `Data of this type is not supported` error.

From my knowledge, an adaptation of this code for WP8 silverlight works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) supports only [base data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br205768.aspx).

Thought if you have a simple `List<string>`, you can make use of *Linq*:

```cs
List<string> l = new List<string>(); // your list with strings
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["locations"] = l.ToArray();
// then when you want to retrive it:
List<string> lret = ((string[])ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["locations"]).ToList();
```

Comment: Solved my problem, and is much simpler then creating an IsolatedStorageFile and saving it as a text document, then rebuilding it into a list. The simplest answer is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for any other data types then primitive ones, you can not use Isolated Storage. For this use, you can use Json Serialization with saving the list to file, and file to isolatedFolder. But you can add strings one by one if you want.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197696/isolated-storage-saving-multiple-objects) an example of isolated storage with json